# Secondary scrollable lists in bootstrap row are hidden

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns

I am using the Solution 1, the [one true layout](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/) solution, from the stackoverflow question [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

When more than 1 column in a bootstrap row is scrollable it seems to get overlapped by the other columns in that row. In the below example, only 1 of the 3 scrollable columns is visible while a similar column that is not scrollable also shows.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/jjr4826/pen/pyENvE)

html

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="row sameHeightRow">
    <div class="col-xs-8 sameHeightCol" style="background-color: grey">
        test <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 sameHeightCol" style="background-color: yellow">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">1</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">b</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">c</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">d</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 scrollable sameHeightCol" style="background-color: yellow">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">2</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">b</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">c</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">d</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 scrollable sameHeightCol" style="background-color: yellow">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">3</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">b</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">c</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">d</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 scrollable sameHeightCol" style="background-color: yellow">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">4</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">b</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">c</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">d</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

css

```
.scrollable{
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow:auto; 
}
.sameHeightRow {
overflow: hidden; 
}
.sameHeightCol {
margin-bottom: -32767px;
padding-bottom: 32767px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [forked your pen](http://codepen.io/tansongyang/pen/vGXdyP).

I guessed that the Bootstrap styles somehow weren't playing nicely with your `.scrollable` and `.sameHeightCol` styles, so what I did was move them to the `<ul>`s like so:

```
<div class="col-xs-1">
  <ul class="list-group scrollable sameHeightCol">
    <!-- <li> -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

This resolved the overlap issue, but then the 4 columns were too tall, so I wrapped them in another div and gave that div a height.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 columnContainer">
  <!-- Original col-xs-1 divs now become col-xs-3 -->
</div>

.columnContainer {
  height: 200px;
}
```

Hope this helps, and let me know if this wasn't what you were trying to achieve.